# creating children using fork and getting segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault, coredump

i am using fork to create 4 children, and each child should add the sum of one fourth of 3 numbers (a,b,and c). for example every child should return (1/4)*(a+b+c). 
Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h> 


struct pol{ 
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

void putValuesInStruct(struct pol *p){
    p->a = 1;
    p->b = 2;
    p->c = 3;
}

int numSum(struct pol *p){
    int a = p->a, b = p->b , c = p->c;
    int sum = (1/4)*(a+b+c);
    return sum;
}

int main(){

    struct pol *p;
    putValuesInStruct(p);

    int i, n=4;
    int arr[4];
    pid_t t [4];

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        arr[i]=0;

    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        if((t[i]=fork())==0){
            arr[i] = numSum(p);
            printf("c%d = %d\n",i,arr[i]);
            exit(0);
        }
        else{
            wait(NULL);
        }
    }
    return 0;

    int sum=0;
    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
        sum+=arr[i];
    printf("sum = %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

The output used to be as follow:

```
c1=0
c2=0
c3=0
c4=0
sum = 0
```

the output should be as follow:

```
c1=(whatever returns from fork)
c2=(whatever returns from fork)
c3=(whatever returns from fork)
c4=(whatever returns from fork)
sum=(the sum of c1+c2+c3+c4)
```

how can i fix this problem? 
however, now i get segmentation fault (core dumped).
how can i make this program run and compile with no errors and faults.

Comment: `p` isn't initialized, so it points to nowhere. Perhaps you fogot to `malloc()` it, or meant to declare p as a struct and pass `&p` to `putValuesInStruct()`.

Comment: I did the & and now i get no core dumped but i still get the output c1 c2 c3 c4 and sum are 0.

Comment: `(1/4)` evaluates to `0`. Use `int sum = (a+b+c) / 4;`

Comment: No, it doesn't work like this **at all**. The memory after fork is just a **copy**, the parent cannot see the changes from the child processes. Perhaps you need threads or posix shared memory!

Answer (score 1):

The crash is due to the bug mentioned in my comment, being p an uninitialized pointer. You must `malloc()` the data or change p to a struct in the stack and pass `&p` instead.

Anyway, it cannot work this way. `fork()` makes a clone of the entire process, so the parent and the forked process don't share data. 
You must either use threads, or use some shared memory segment as an ipc. see `shm_overview` man page here http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html

Answer (score 0):

```
struct pol *p;
putValuesInStruct(p);
```

As mentioned in comment by HappyCactus, you need to allocate memory to `p` prior to passing it to your function, where you are assigning values to structure members